# Compile Error on vector initialization in return statement

Tags: c++, vector, return

I just want to do some initial checks, and have some quick of {-1, -1} vector  return if necessary. Somehow, compiler says: I should change return type into vector *

But the current return type works for my later parts before I do this pre-checks code. So what do I misunderstood?

```
class SomeClass {
  public:
    static vector<int> solution(vector<int>& numbers, int target) {
      if (numbers.empty() || numbers.size() < 2) {
        return new vector<int> {-1, -1};   // <== Compile Error
      }
      unordered_map<int, int> hash;
      vector<int> result;
      .
      .
      .
      return result;
    }
};

int main() {
  vector<int> testNums = {11, 15, 2, 7};
  vector<int> result = SomeClass::solution(testNums, 9);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove keyword `new`

Comment: And `vector <int>` - the compiler will figure that bit out for itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Somehow, compiler says: I should change return type into `vector *`

In C++, you need a pointer (or a *pointer-like* type) to point dynamically allocated memory.

Thus, replacing:

```
return new vector<int> {-1, -1};
```

with:

```
return { -1, -1 };
```

will make it work as you'd expect.